# SUM conditional logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following 2 tables in SQL Server 2012:

```
|=================|  
|ID|SALARY|EXCLUDE|  
| 1| 90000|   NULL|  
| 1| 65000|   NULL|  
| 1| 10000|      Y|  
| 2| 85000|   NULL|  
| 2|  4500|      Y|  
| 2|  1000|      Y|  
| 3| 75000|   NULL|  
|=================|

|===========|  
|ID|CONTRACT|  
| 1|  155000|  
| 2|   85000|  
| 3|   75000|  
|===========|
```

I need to write a query that returns the following results:

```
|===========================|  
|ID|CONTRACT|EXCLUDED SALARY|  
| 1|  155000|          10000|  
| 2|   85000|           5500|  
| 3|   75000|           NULL|  
|===========================|
```

In other words, I need to sum the SALARY field in the first table for each ID if EXCLUDE is Y.  I know how to sum the salary column but I don't understand how to include the EXCLUDE logic.  Any help you can give me is very much appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    A.ID, 
    B.CONTRACT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN EXCLUDE = 'Y' then SALARY END) EXCLUDED_SALARY
FROM TABLE_SALARY A
INNER JOIN TABLE_CONTRACT B
   ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY A.ID, B.CONTRACT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation to only count salaries where the exclude flag is Y in the sum:

```
sum(case when exclude = 'Y' then salary end)
```